# I can't figure out how to render a new page with updated json data

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

I'm not sure where my error is. I am new to node and I have been doing A LOT of learning. The process has been a bit of a rush because it is a summer class so it is fast paced. I know my routes/controllers are weird and this is NOT the best format. I plan to "fix" this project later after deadline is done.

I need my results fetched from AJAX and put inside my post.ejs file. When the user clicks on a title in my index.ejs I want it to redirect them to my post.ejs file with the correct post.title and post.content

Here is my Ajax for an `onclick` function to be called

```
$("#thisTitle").on("click", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var post = $(this).text();

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/post/" + post,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
      location.assign("/post");
    },
  });
});
```

Here is my index.ejs file

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div id="containerBlogPost">
      <div class="blogPost">
        <a href="">
          <h3 class="resize" id="thisTitle"><%= posts[0].title %></h3>
        </a>
        <p class="resize">
          "<%= posts[0].content %>"
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And finally, here are my GET requests

```
app.get("/post/:item", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const post = await Post.findOne({ title: req.params.item });
    res.json({
      title: post.title,
      content: post.content,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ message: err });
  }
});

app.get("/post", function (req, res) {
  Post.find({}, function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.render("post", { posts: data });
  });
});
```

Here is my post.ejs where I am trying to access the dynamic json data

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <%- include('partials/header'); -%>

    <div class="post-page">
      <div class="postContainer">
        <div class="postTitle">
          <h3 id="singlePostTitle"><%= test %></h3>
        </div>

        <div class="blogPostPage" id="singlePostContent"><%= test %>"</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I access my GET request `/post/:item` on postman I get the result I intend to fetch. I just don't know how to use that `json` data and pass it correctly into ajax to render a /post page with the dynamic data of `/post/:item`

Comment: Need to ask few question as per my understanding you want to show the results fetched from ajax in post.ejs file?

Comment: That is correct, Anku. I have updated the question to provide a few more details.

Answer (score 0):

With the ajax call you get `JSON` that correspond to the data of the post you are looking for and it is supposed to use its data in the same document in this case index.ejs. When the JSON is achieved in the `$ajax` callback `success`, you redirect to another document and the JSON remains unused. Maybe you should rethink what you want to do, you could for example show the post obtained in ajax in the same view `index.ejs`, for example

In `index.ejs` add the div with class output

```
<div class="blogPost">
  <div class="output"></div> <!-- add this element -->
  <a href="">
    <h3 class="resize" id="thisTitle"><%= posts[0].title %></h3>
  </a>
  <p class="resize">
    "<%= posts[0].content %>"
  </p>
</div>
```

In javascript

```
$("#thisTitle").on("click", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var post = $(this).text();

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/post/" + post,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
      document.querySelector(".output").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data);

      // location.assign("/post");
    },
  });
});
```

What is relevant is that you understand the context in which the result of the call to ajax is supposed to be used, I hope this will be useful to you

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get you completely, but I get that you want to pass JSON data to and fro AJAX script and Router file. Below is the code which will help you to do so:

To pass data from AJAX to Router (using POST Method:
Script.js (AJAX):

```
            $.ajax({
                url: '/post/'+post,
                method: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json', // to set header content-type
                dataType: 'json', // must be defined
                data: JSON.stringify(data), // 'data' is the files you want to pass to the router (in your case it is 'title'
                success: function(res){
                    console.log('data passed success fully')
                },
                error: function(){
                    console.log('error')
                }
            })
```

Router.js:

```
app.post("/post/:item", function (req, res) {
  console.log(res.body)
});`
```

To pass data from Router to AJAX (using GET method):
Router.js:

```
app.get("/post", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const post = await Post.findOne({ title: req.params.item });
    res.json({
      title: post.title,
      content: post.content,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ message: err });
  }
});
```

Script.js (AJAX):

```
             $.ajax({
                    url: '/post',
                    method: 'GET',
                    success: function(res){
                        console.log(res.title)
                        console.log(res.content)
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        console.log('error')
                    }
                })
```